# Bug in VectorFieldPlot[] with InterpolatingFunction[]?

Tags: plotting, bugs, evaluation, interpolation

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.0.0 or later**

---

While looking at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192081/how-do-i-plot-a-divergence, I thought to suggest the following as a solution to the OP's problem (where `potdistr` is an `InterpolatingFunction` solution to a PDE returned by `NDSolve`):

```
VectorDensityPlot[
 Evaluate[Grad[potdistr[x, y], {x, y}]],
 {x, -0.01, 0.11}, {y, -0.005, 0.053}]
```

I surprised that it worked once and then failed on subsequent calls.  It seems to be connected to `InterpolatingFunction` and values being set for `x` and `y`.  Here is a minimal example:

```
field = {Interpolation[Range[4]^2/4][y], x};
VectorDensityPlot[field, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}]
```

Subsequent calls generate a `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` extrapolation warning message and the vector field is constant.

The problem does not occur if `field = {y^2/4, x}` is used.  It does not occur for `VectorPlot`, `DensityPlot`, `ContourPlot`, or `Plot3D`.

What's going on? Is it a bug? Is there a way to get it to work?

*Additional info:*

```
$Version
(*  "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 22, 2018)"  *)
```

Filed as [CASE:4228039], confirmed by WRI.

Comment: I was fiddling with the same problem, and had odd results when attempting to do a StreamPlot of the gradient of potexpr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that `x` and `y` are being set equal to numeric values.  (One might notice that the color for `x` and `y` changes from blue to black, but my eyes have trouble seeing that for single-letter variables.)  For some reason, these values are outside the domain specified in the plot.  I think this must be a bug and have reported it to WRI.

```
Clear[x, y]
{x, y}
field = {Interpolation[Range[4]^2/4][y], x};
VectorDensityPlot[field, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}]
{x, y}
```

[image]

One possible workaround is to clear the variables after plotting with `Clear[x, y]`.  Another is to use `Block`:

```
Block[{x, y}, VectorDensityPlot[field, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}]]
```

Further, it does not seem restricted only to `InterpolatingFunction`.  The following has the same issue, and, further, `VectorStyle` is ignored:

```
Clear[x, y, ff]
{x, y}
ff[xx_, yy_] := {yy^2/4, xx};
VectorDensityPlot[ff[x, y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, VectorStyle -> Red]
{x, y}
(*  output is the same as above, same coloring  *)
```

Pre-evaluating `ff[x, y]` gives the desired plot:

```
VectorDensityPlot[Evaluate@ff[x, y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, VectorStyle -> Red]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works...once you have `potdistr`, run this to get a `Function`

```
pdg = Evaluate[Grad[potdistr[#1, #2], {#1, #2}]] &
```

You can then run the plot function repeatedly, no problem, and go back and run previous statements (you couldn't when `x, y` were getting set).

```
VectorDensityPlot[pdg[x,y], {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
VectorDensityPlot[pdg[x,y], {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
VectorDensityPlot[pdg[x,y], {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
```

[image]

You can also run this kludgy version, but it is slow.

```
VectorDensityPlot[Evaluate[Grad[potdistr[#1, #2], {#1, #2}]] &[x, y], 
                  {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
```

I was interested in the not very useful looking `StreamPlot` I was getting.

```
StreamPlot[pdg[x, y], {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}]
```

[image]

One thing I found odd is that if you look at the domain for potdistr versus the plot ranges people are using, there should be some extrapolation going on. Shouldn't we get warnings for that?

Comment: Can you explain why the first method works?  It might be worth pointing out that `VectorDensityPlot` still sets `x` and `y` here, but this method gets around the trouble it causes in other methods.

Comment: Frankly I’m not sure of the details, but it seems a best practice to define functions this way anyway.

Comment: On the one hand, it's because `pdg` does not depend on `x` or `y`.  Instead, the gradient is computed by differentiating the function with respect to `#1` and `#2` (`Slot[1]` and `Slot[2]`) which are `Protected`.  Mathematica allows this use of `#1` and `#2`, which is convenient here. On the other hand, the `x` and `y` inside `VectorDensityPlot[pdg[x, y],...]` are effectively localized using `Block`. This means that any global values for `x` and `y` are temporarily cleared before the plot is calculated....

Comment: ....From these two reasons. your approach, while not preventing `x` and `y` from from being overwritten, solves the major problem of making the plot work. [Obviously, I knew the answer.  I just thought the answer would be improved by an explanation, for others who are looking to understand *Mathematica* better. Since it's your answer, I was encouraging you to add such an explanation.]

Comment: I like your explanation better. :)  It's not always clear to me how an `InterpolatingFunction's` are set.