# Bug in VectorDensityPlot assigning variables

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and fixed in 13.2 or earlier**

---

I notice that after a call to VectorDensityPlot the variables used are assigned to random real values. This doesn't seem to happen with VectorPlot and I can't find a notice of bug. It's been mentioned in other posts (e.g. [Bug in VectorFieldPlot[] with InterpolatingFunction[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192118/bug-in-vectorfieldplot-with-interpolatingfunction)). Is this a know bug? Does it affect all versions (I'm on 11.3)? Is there a suggested `Block`? `Evaluator`?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[xy_] := {xy[[1]]*xy[[1]] - xy[[1]] - xy[[2]]*xy[[2]], 
  2 xy[[1]] xy[[2]] - xy[[2]] + Pi}

{x, xa, ya}
VectorPlot[f[{xa, ya}] - {xa, ya}, {xa, -2, 3}, {ya, -2, 2}, 
 VectorScale -> Medium, VectorPoints -> Fine]
VectorDensityPlot[f[{xb, yb}] - {xb, yb}, {xb, -2, 3}, {yb, -2, 2}, 
 VectorScale -> Medium, VectorPoints -> Fine]
{x, xa, ya, xb, yb}
```

[image: xb,yb assigned after VectorDensityPlot]

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in `12.0` but **NOT** in `13.2`. I would call that a bug.